# Get digits outside a quote regex

Tags: javascript, regex

trying to find the right regex to catch digits that are outside quotes. For exemple, in :

```
444545564 fcf456 f46 ref 464 f64ff4rfrfr'45'4778,458
```

I would like to get only

```
444545564 456 46 464 64 4 4778 458
```

I am now using this kind of regex :

```
[^'a-z\/,\s]\d+[^'a-z\/,\s]
```

But the thing is that it doesn't give me the numbers under 3 digits like 46, 64 or 4 (which seems to be normal).

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Can the string contain escape sequences? `1 \'2\' '33'` -> and then `1` and `2` are expected?

Comment: why dont you just `.replace(/'\d+'/g,'')` then match the resulting string for numbers?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew In your example, `1` is expected but not `2` and `3`

Comment: @engineeriscool might have been interesting but the rest of my code is not made so that I can do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming* the single quotes are balanced and no escape sequences are to be considered, you may match `'...'` substrings, and match and capture all digit chunks in other contexts (see more about this technique at [*The Best Regex Trick Ever (at last!)*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick)):

```
/'[^']*'|(\d+)/g
```

**Details**:

- `'[^']*'` - `'` followed with 0+ chars other than `'` and then a `'`
- `|` - or
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 capturing one or more digits.

See JS demo below:

```js
var s = "444545564 fcf456 f46 ref 464 f64ff4rfrfr'45'4778,458";
var res = [], m;
var rx = /'[^']*'|(\d+)/g;
while(m=rx.exec(s)) {
  if (m[1]) res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Mmmmh the regex works fine, but when I am trying to use a `replace` in my code, itdoes what it is supposed to do for the numbers but also changes all my quoted stuff to `undefined` (which is not that cool)

Comment: Meh, just added a condition and now it works. Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: @PaaBliiTo: Sorry, I was out for a walk (note it is very important when coding is what you do for a living!). If you mentioned you need to *replace*, I would provide it. If you need to replace the *digits*, you need to use a callback inside a `replace`. If you need to *remove*, you need to capture the part you need to keep, and use `$1` backreference to that group in the replacement pattern. Glad you figured that out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one `/[^'](\d+)(?!')/g` and use group 1

```js
const regex = /[^'](\d+)(?!')/g;
const str = `444545564 fcf456 f46 ref 464 f64ff4rfrfr'45'4778,458`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach(function(match, groupIndex) {
        if(groupIndex === 1) {
          console.log(match);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This won't work if there are non-digit chars inside `'...'` (e.g. `aa 2 'e45' 3`). Also, `if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {   regex.lastIndex++;  }` is redundant, you are no expecting any zero-length matches here.

Comment: You're right, mine works with original question but yours also handles this case.

Comment: Besides, using a single negated character class at the start will prevent matching numbers at the start of the string. A common work around is to use an alternation with the start of string anchor: `(^|[^'])`